# No connection and no energy on mission To the mun via Minmus

Tags: kerbal-space-program

During the **Making History Expansion** mission **To the Mun via Minmus**, I run out of energy even with the probe in Hibernate and both RTC + SAS off.

Is there a way to make the probe stop using any energy?

Since the probe is pre-built and we can't install solar panels to it, I don't know what to do.

Here is a picture of the probe almost flying by Minmun with enough fuel to enter orbit but not enough energy.

NOTE: I think the antenna not connected to the Kerbin is because the probe ran out of energy.

[image]

Comment: afaik even with probes in hibernation you will still drain energy, try turning your engines on to very low thrust in order to generate some electricity?

Comment: @lI that was my first thought but I would deviate a lot from my way and would burn a lot of fuel making it impossible to finish the mission. There must be a tricky way that I don't know to arrive there with some juice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/KerbalSpaceProgram/comments/84h945/how_to_beat_to_the_mun_via_minmus_mission_in_the/), the pre-built probe for this mission has *two* probe cores: the obvious Stayputnik core on the top, and a second HECS(?) core hidden between the monoprop tanks and the batteries:

[image: Location of second probe core]
<sup>Image from Reddit thread linked above, presumably by Reddit user djdupre.</sup>

To stop the power from draining too fast, you'll have to hibernate *both* of these probe cores.

(Ps. I'm marking this answer as Community Wiki, since I don't really feel justified in taking credit for just quoting someone else's answer from another site.  I can't even really test this myself, since I don't have the expansion.  The screenshot does appear to confirm the existence of the second probe core if you look closely, though.)

(Pps. There's [another Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/KerbalSpaceProgram/comments/84hbne/is_the_mission_to_the_mun_via_minmus_solvable/) that says the same thing, and notes a few other issues with the mission as well.)

NOTE: Here is the image showing the HECS that you need to hibernate. It is located below the GRAVMAX Negative Gravioli Detector. This image was taken on the land site before launching:
[image]

Comment: That's correct. Once I hibernated both cores, I arrived Minmun with 500+ Electric Charge. It still drains something, but very little.

Comment: Do you have any reaction wheels enabled?